# Vector with names and selection partial selection of string variables (R)

Tags: r, string, vector, subset

I had several outputs from a statistical test. These outputs are in a form of a numeric vector with names. For example, the first 4 values of one of my outputs are:

```
a <- c(-2.676570e-08,-2.653513e-08,-2.612869e-08,-2.586143e-08);
b <- setNames(a,c("0.6234414% ","1.6209476%","2.6184539%","3.6159601% ")) 
class(b)
# "numeric"
```

I will like to select the value that match a specific %, for example the value equivalent to the 2% category. However I have been unsuccessful

I tried the function `grep`

```
(grep("2.", b, value=TRUE))
#     0.6234414%       1.6209476%      2.6184539%     3.6159601%  
# "-2.67657e-08" "-2.653513e-08" "-2.612869e-08" "-2.586143e-08"
```

However it returns the whole vector

My understanding of defining the pattern is that it will try to match the expression between the "". Is there other rules or characters I need to use when the names are a set of string-numbers?

Comment: What exactly do you want as a result from your example?  Not sure you want `grep()`, as it will coerce the result to character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  two issues:

1) You want to index `names(b)` not `b` itself.
2) `.` means "any character" in regular expressions used in `grep()`, `grepl()`, `regexpr()` etc, so you have to escape it with `\\`

So use something like:

```
b[grep("2\\.",names(b))]
#   2.6184539% 
#-2.612869e-08 

b[grepl("2\\.",names(b))]
#   2.6184539% 
#-2.612869e-08
```